# Venn Diagram Probability Question

Tags: probability

For two events $A$ and $B$ we have $\text{Pr}(A′) = 0.71$, $\text{Pr}(B) = 0.43$, and
$\text{Pr}(A\cup B) = 0.65$.

Find $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)$.

I know the answer is $0.07$. I just can't seem to figure out how.

For $A$ I found the probability was $0.22$ (Just the left portion of the circle not overlapping B.)

That is as far as I am able to get. Working on a practice exam for tomorrow's test. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fixed up the formatting, leaving $A'$ as it is.  Can you confirm this means the complement of $A$, i.e. not $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Venn Diagram should have two overlapping circles (A, B) with the three sections labelled $A\setminus B, A\cap B, B\setminus A$.

From the information given you know that $\Pr(A\setminus B)=\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(B)=0.65-0.43=0.22\quad$ (Note: this is **not** $\Pr(A)$)

Similarly you should find $\Pr(A)=1-\Pr(A')=1-0.71=0.29$ and thus $\Pr(B\setminus A)=\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A) =\underline{\qquad}$.

The middle area is $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A\setminus B)-\Pr(B\setminus A) =\underline{\qquad}$

---

Alternatively, you could use: $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B) =\underline{\qquad}$

Answer (score 0):

Since the question contains the keyword `venn`, let me do it the venn's way :

Consider this image : 
[image]

It describes your problem :

$Pr(A')$ = White + Yellow + Green = $0.71$

$Pr(B)$ = Green + Yellow = $0.43$

$Pr(A\cup B)$ = Red + Yellow + Green = $0.65$

And you want to find $Pr(A\cap B)$ (Yellow):

You can find whatever you want only by playing with those colors, keeping in mind the sum of all of them equals $1$

$Pr(A)$ = Red + Yellow

$Pr(B)$ = Green + Yellow

$Pr(A\cup B$ = Red + Yellow + Green

```
         = (Red + Yellow) + (Green + Yellow) - Yellow

         = $Pr(A)$ + $P(B)$ - $P(A\cap B)$ ... $(1)$
```

I'll live it to you to complete ...